# Powershell Script- Send automatatic email when The Task in Task Scheduler Fails to Run

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I automate a BAT file to powershell script. The Task is set to run Every 1 hr, Daily to backup the database.

I need to set an auto e-mail generator only if the Task fails to run.

Can you help how can I do this? Should I use compare_object to define it.

Any help is appreciated.

thank You!!

Comment: When you say "task fails to run" do you mean that the task ran, but produced an error? Do you mean that the task failed to run at the expected time? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BoogaRoo Hello, Yes- The Task failed to run at the expected time, and also if it produce an error. Confused with what conditions I should setup with. I havn't done much with powershell before. I tried access the InputObject property of  Compare-Object output, but don't think I am on right direction.